# How to analyze SQL statement execution time fluctuation?

Tags: sql, hana

I know this question is not easy to give an actual answer, but I met it sometimes, SQL execution time is high but cannot reproduce 100%, actually very casually.

here, I just want to get the general way to how to find the root cause, which aspects should I pay more attention to? and please note 1 point, I was doing it on HANA DB (from SAP).

Thanks!

Comment: adding some background, I am a performance engineer , not DBA, so I need some suggestions on how to track this kind of issue.

Comment: It depends on whether it is a table or a view. Does the runtime depend on the parameters of the query?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to analyze the script execution with available tools like SAP HANA SQL analyzer app Plan Graph or Timeline

If you know the time when the SQL query took too much time, you can analyze the time range for memory usage with Memory Analysis application as well

Answer (score 0):

When looking at runtime variations, several factors can come into play, such as

- changed data, both in volume and variety (check the statement's selection/grouping conditions and the data in the referenced tables)
- changed system load during query execution (other queries/activities running? delta merge? data load? backup?)
- system cpu power settings not set correctly (if the CPU perf. gets throttled, this can have quite an effect)

SAP notes [1969700 - SQL Statement Collection for SAP HANA](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1969700) and [2000002 - FAQ: SAP HANA SQL Optimization](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2000002) are great starting points for the analysis, just as the [SAP HANA Troubleshooting and Performance Analysis Guide](https://help.sap.com/viewer/bed8c14f9f024763b0777aa72b5436f6/2.0.02/en-US)